# MagicalRecord ios migrating not seeing migrated data

Tags: ios, core-data, migration, magicalrecord

I am trying to migrate a ios core data database using MagicalRecord. I added a few attributes and I renamed a entity.  I setup the mappings and from what it looks like it worked.

The problem I am having is on initial migration, the migrated data is not showing up.  It is in the .sqlite file, but not seeing it on the tables.  If I shut down the app and restart the date is there.

Does anyone know if I have to change the inContext in my fetch request to see this data on initial migration?

Comment: You _are_ setting up your core data stack with the `setupAutoMigratingDefaultCoreDataStack` or `setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:` methods on the MagicalRecord class, right?

Comment: Yes, I am setting up the core data stack to with setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed.  I did find that I was renaming the entity and using a migration class to migrate the records.  Once I reverted to the old entity name, it worked.

Comment: I ended up just keeping the entity name the same and migration is working fine.

Comment: If you want to use auto migration facilities of MagicalRecord, then the migration must be a "Lightweight Migration" according to core data. If you've renamed an entity, typically this is _not_ a lightweight migration, unless you have set the renaming identifier in both the source and destination models. Check out [Lightweight Migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweightMigration.html) for more info on this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I didn't know rename of the entity was not lightweight migration.